# Как найти первый элемент в массиве и если он пустой то вставить или удалить?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Как при загрузке проверить, если в массиве product.thumbs есть пустой элемент (первый найденный) с image === '' то в него вставить данные, если в массиве нет пустых значений то просто запушить в массив

сам массив

```
product: {
        thumbs: [
          {
            image: '',
            thumb: '',
          },
          {
            image: '',
            thumb: '',
          },
          {
            image: '',
            thumb: '',
          },
          {
            image: '',
            thumb: '',
          },
        ],
}
```

и функция загрузки

```
uploadGallery() {
      const that = this
      const galleries = event.target.files
      galleries.forEach(function (value, index, product) {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('image', value)
        formData.append('path', 'products')
        that.$axios
          .$post('/api/v1/shop/1/upload/image', formData, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
          })
          .then((response) => {
            if (!that.product.image) {
              that.product.image = response.path + response.image
            }
            
            that.product.thumbs.push({
              image: response.image,
              path: response.path,
            })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
          })
        return index < that.countThumb + 1
      })
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так

```js
let product = {
        thumbs: [
          {
            image: '',
            thumb: '',
          },
          {
            image: '',
            thumb: '',
          },
          {
            image: '',
            thumb: '',
          },
          {
            image: '',
            thumb: '',
          }
        ]
}

if (product.thumbs.find(item => item.image === "") != null) {
  product.thumbs.find(item => item.image === "").image = "response.path " + "response.image"
}

product.thumbs.push({
  image: "response.image",
  path: "response.path"
})

console.log(product)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через функцию. Так можно получить не только image,  но и любой указанный  key.

```
let product = {
        thumbs: [
          {
            image: 'Не пустой  image',
            thumb: '2',
          },
          {
            image: 'Не пустой  image',
            thumb: '4',
          },
          {
            image: 'Не пустой  image',
            thumb: '',
          },
          {
            image: '',
            thumb: '',
          }
        ] 
} 

function findEmptyValue(arr, key) {  
   return arr.map(el => el[key].length === 0 ? 'image' : el);
} 
console.log(findEmptyValue(product.thumbs, 'image'));
```